# Image population dynamically in a div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to populate a image dynamically by iterating an object(ng-repeat)

please find the codes below

```
<div class="row graph-img">
    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="option in subserviceObject.serviceRequest">
    <img ng-init="retreiveGraph(service,subservice,$index)" id="imgframe{{$index}}" src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller code is here

```
$scope.retreiveGraph = function(serviceName,subservice,index) {
    $scope.service=serviceName;
    $scope.resetGrapghParam(serviceName,subservice,num);
    $scope.displayServiceDetails(serviceName);
    imgsrc='./service/getServiceDetails/'+$scope.service+'/'+$scope.initGrapghServiceName;
    document.getElementById("imgframe"+index).setAttribute("src", imgsrc);
};
```

I am getting an error in console like "Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null".

if this is the wrong way of tackling this solution, Please suggest me to solve this issue.

please find my final HTML elements after rendering

```
<div class="row graph-img">
    <!-- ngRepeat: option in subserviceObject.serviceRequest --><div class="col-sm-6 ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in subserviceObject.serviceRequest">
    <img ng-init="retreiveGraph(service,subservice,$index)" id="imgframe0" src="">
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: option in subserviceObject.serviceRequest -->
<div class="col-sm-6 ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in subserviceObject.serviceRequest">
    <img ng-init="retreiveGraph(service,subservice,$index)" id="imgframe1" src="">
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: option in subserviceObject.serviceRequest --><div class="col-sm-6 ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in subserviceObject.serviceRequest">
    <img ng-init="retreiveGraph(service,subservice,$index)" id="imgframe2" src="">
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: option in subserviceObject.serviceRequest -->
</div>
```

id is populating correctly but when I try to setAttribute it is returning as null

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't do DOM manipulation in your controller. Use `ng-src`

Comment: You can't access the id since it is not as part of DOM yet

Comment: Thanks! Could you check the answer as accepted also, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has a directive to construct the src of the img tags, use it:

```
<div class="row graph-img">
    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="option in subserviceObject.serviceRequest">
    <img ng-src="retreiveGraph(service,subservice,$index)">
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.retreiveGraph = function(serviceName, subservice, index) {
    $scope.service=serviceName;
    $scope.resetGrapghParam(serviceName,subservice,num);
    $scope.displayServiceDetails(serviceName);
    return './service/getServiceDetails/' + $scope.service + '/' + $scope.initGrapghServiceName;
};
```

Although I think you have  missunderstood some concepts of Angulars, such as $scope and others. I suggest that you read some documentation before going on with this...

You don't need to pass the parameters into the function for each iteration, if you have them on the $scope objects you can get them from there directly.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I am a server side programmer recently entered into UI,
concepts getting mixed up.

Comment: I never know that ng-src can call a function.

Comment: ng-src={{retreiveGraph(service,subservice,$index)}}.  It should be in double brace to consider that as a function. Else it is considering that as a url.